# lexical scope in Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, lexical-scope

in the following code snippet, I defined "bob" first, but the output is "alice:1 hi alice", I don't know why?

```js
let user = "";
function greet() {
  console.count(user);
  return `hi ${user}`;
}
user = "bob";
user = "alice";
console.log(greet());//alice:1 hi alice
```

Comment: variable assignments happen before the function call. By the time you call the function, the value of `user` is `alice` there for that is what it prints. I am not entirely sure where you confusion is.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing scope with value? Still, I’m not sure why that would lead you to expect `hi bob` rather than just `hi `, since `user = ""` first of all.

Comment: @Ry-: In my opinion, I defined "bob" first, so "bob" should come before "alice". So, when a function is called, the engine first looks for the closest variable, not the first declared variable, right? Noooooo! I got it now! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is *hi alice* because, by the time `greet()` is executed, the variable is reassigned to *alice*.

If you want the count to reflect the *bob* value, you should call `greet()` any time before its value is changed.

**Demo:**

```js
let user = "";
function greet() {
  console.count(user);
  return `hi ${user}`;
}

user = "bob";
console.log(greet()); //hi bob

user = "alice";
console.log(greet()); //hi alice
```

Answer (score 0):

in this code snippet, we have a variable and a function, as much as it is related to lexical scope, the variable is defined outside the function , it means all the code outside the function and inside the function has access to the variable, that is all about scope.

but about the value of the user, since you call the function after the variable was assigned to alice so what it prints is alice